# Trying to make a centered - unless too long - one line, picture heading using css

Tags: css

I am trying to make a picture heading that works like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|   Short Title                                             |
| +-------------+                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| |  (picture)  |                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| +-------------+                                           |
|                                                           |
|                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| This is a much longer title (wider than the picture)      |
| +-------------+                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| |  (picture)  |                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| +-------------+                                           |
|                                                           |
|                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| This is a ridiculously long title - and who cares about...|
| +-------------+                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| |  (picture)  |                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| |             |                                           |
| +-------------+                                           |
|                                                           |
|                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The first two were easily accomplish (on a paragraph or span) with this bit of css:

```
.mydivclass > p {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipses;    /* what I would like to happen */
    min-width: 100px;           /* the picture width */
    margin-left: 10px;          /* the picture left margin */
}
```

Getting the ellipses at the end of the first line is elusive.  I know multiline clamping is a challenge, but I thought a single line should be easier.  I played around a bit with using a readonly input field, but flexible sizing of input fields seems problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "CSS Grid" to accomplish the layout you want. 
"CSS grid" is a CSS built-in grid system.
See attached code snippet.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  1fr
  1fr
  1fr
  1fr
  1fr
  1fr
  ;
  grid-template-rows:
  80px
  150px
  200px
  ;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header header"
    "picture picture . . . ."
    "rest-of-area rest-of-area rest-of-area rest-of-area rest-of-area rest-of-area"
    ;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 80px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.picture {
  grid-area: picture;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 10px 70px 0px 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

<div class="header">Have a lot of text here is not a problem...</div>
<div class="picture"></div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Toolbox.  Actually, your solution has the same problem mine does - when the text gets past the end of the line, it wraps (run your snippet and change text to "Have a lot of text here is not a problem even if its very, very, very, long").  Goal is to have long text get chopped off and ellipses at the end of the line.  So something like "Have a lot of text here is not a problem even if its very..."  Also, I need to let CSS grid age a bit more before I can deploy it (most browsers started supporting it by default last year).